# Batch cypher queries generated by RestCypherQueryEngine

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to batch together a few cypher queries with the REST API (using the java bindings library) so that only one call is made over the wire. But it seems to not respect the batching on the client side and gives this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.batch.RecordingRestRequest.toMap(RecordingRestRequest.java:138)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:509)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:233)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2709)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:55)
    ... 41 more
```

This is how I am trying to batch them:

```
graphDatabaseService.getRestAPI().executeBatch(new BatchCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void recordBatch(RestAPI batchRestApi) {
                String query =  "CREATE accounts=({userId:{userId}})-[r:OWNS]->({facebookId:{facebookId}})";
                graphDatabaseService.getQueryEngine().query(query, map("userId", 1, "facebookId", "1"));
                graphDatabaseService.getQueryEngine().query(query, map("userId", 2, "facebookId", "2"));
                graphDatabaseService.getQueryEngine().query(query, map("userId", 3, "facebookId", "3"));


                return null;
            }
        });
```

I am using noe4j version 1.9 and the corresponding client library.  Should this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JUnit sample code that works for your batch. Here no string template is used but native methods on the RestAPI object:

```
public static final DynamicRelationshipType OWNS = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("OWNS");

@Autowired
private SpringRestGraphDatabase             graphDatabaseService;

@Test
public void batchTest()
    {

    Assert.assertNotNull(this.graphDatabaseService);

    this.graphDatabaseService.getRestAPI().executeBatch(new BatchCallback<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public Void recordBatch(RestAPI batchRestApi)
                {
                for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++)
                    {
                    RestNode userId = batchRestApi.createNode(map("userId", Integer.valueOf(counter)));
                    RestNode facebookId = batchRestApi.createNode(map("facebookId", Integer.valueOf(counter).toString()));
                    batchRestApi.createRelationship(userId, facebookId, OWNS, map());
                    }
                return null;
                }
        });

    }
```

Comment: By the way: I found this RestAPI test case: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/BatchRestAPITest.java

Comment: I was actually looking to batch hardcoded cypher query themselves.  I ended up doing this by using a simple jersey client that hits the neo4j server batch endpoint and just encoding the queries to json myself.  Thanks though!